# Decimal to hexadecimal conversion: issues with sprintf?

Tags: c, printf

I have a requirement, part of which needs conversion from  decimal to hex.

I prefer the following way to do that thing as below:

```
sprintf(mcc,"%x",n);
```

`n` here will be an integer.
But my peer says it is not a good way to do that.
Instead he says to manually convert the decimal using a function,
but I did not get a good explanation about why not to use sprintf.

Are there any problems with the above method I am using?

Should I go for a function which manually converts the decimal number into hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you make sure that the buffer pointed to by `mcc` is big enough for the resulting string, I see no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `sprintf` is that it's hard to guarantee your buffer is big enough.  Use `snprintf` instead.

In this case the maximum possible output length is small and easily calculated, but it's not always this easy, and my guess is that this is why your friend told you not to use `sprintf`.

Comment: this is generally true, but here Rahul is converting a number to an hex, it is much easier to have mcc of the right size.

Comment: It's not really hard in this case **if** you know the range of `n`. E.g.: for 0<=n<=65535 the "biggest" hexadecimal is FFFF, thus, a buffer size of 5 should do.

Comment: Yes, in this case the output should be small enough, but in general length checking versions should be preferred, and my guess is that this is why his friend advised against `sprintf`.

Comment: Yeah the maximum size i will receive is char[4].eg:f262.so i am taking mcc as char mcc[4];i hope thsi works fine.

Comment: @RahulDravid you actually need `char[5]`, one extra to hold the null terminator (\0 at the end).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a machine which supports the GNU extensions then you can use `asprintf` as well. This will allocate heap memory, store the string in it and then give you a pointer to this. Just make sure you `free` the string when you're done with it.